# octopress + github trouble: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: github, octopress

Do you know anything about [octopress](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/)? I tried doing

```
rake setup_github_pages
Repository url: monsieurcactus.github.com
```

Then it says

```
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My github page is

> https://github.com/MonsieurCactus/monsieurcactus.github.com

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [issue 516](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/516):

> oh! it works!
>   you could try this command:

```
$ rake setup_github_pages
$ Enter the read/write url for your repository: git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com.git
```

> you should create a project named "`your_username.github.com`" first, the full project name is "`your_username.github.com`"
>
> I was surprised that using a `git://github.com/uname/reponame` address didn't work.
>   ([Issue 666](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/pull/666))
>
> For example, '`git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com`'